# PostgreSQL: After transforming SRID to 32650, openstreet map doesn't show correct location, working on DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, geometry, srid

I have two shapefile geometries where i need to transform the dataset SRID from wgs84 to wgs84/UTM zone 50N ie, 32650 in postgresql.

select st_transform(geom, 32650) from boundary b;
select st_transform(geom, 32650) from road r ;

the SRID gets transformed but when i see the geometries on openstreet map the location has changed.
how can I make sure that the location is correct on map?